# What is the list of all valid character encodings that could be used in XML?

Tags: xml, character-encoding

I am looking for the list of all valid character encoding names that could be used by an XML document to specify the document's character encoding. A list such as the following:

```
UTF-8
UTF-16
US-ASCII
ISO-8859-1
ISO-8859-2
Big5
```

According to w3c.org, the list of all valid names are here: http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xml. However, I do not see "UTF-16" in the left-most column and would expect it to be present as a valid encoding.

Can someone please point me to the canonical list of all valid charsets?

Comment: "UTF-16" *is* present in the list...!?

Comment: It is present in the second column, yes, but not in the first column, which unless I am mistaken, are the set of encoding names you would use. For example, you wouldn't write "encoding=ISO_8859-1:1987" (which is present in the second column), instead you would write "encoding=ISO_8859-1" (which is present in the first column). So I'm looking for a list of valid encoding names, which look like the names in that first column but which includes all valid, canonical encoding names and not just a subset.

Comment: To be clear, while the second column does appears to contain names for encodings, while valid conceptually, not all are valid canonical character encoding names that you would use when declaring the encoding type in your XML. I am looking for that list. The reason I care to know this canonical list of names is that I am defining a feed file format that should be able to accept most major character encodings, but I need to know what the full list of possible encodings is, and I need the list to show me the EXACT standardized encoding names, not just names that are conceptually correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any character encoding can be used with XML, as long as it is specified in the `encoding` attribute of the prolog.  Only UTF-8 and UTF-16 do not need to be specified, but UTF-16 does require a BOM, at least.

Comment: The relevant clause in the the XML 1.0 specification is http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charencoding and it contains several recommendations, but no normative requirements beyond those stated in the answer. For example, it is valid to use a privately agreed encoding, between interested parties.

Comment: Per the link, I am looking for the IANA-registered name of the encoding - "It is RECOMMENDED that character encodings registered (as charsets) with the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority [IANA-CHARSETS], other than those just listed, be referred to using their registered name... XML processors SHOULD match character encoding names in a case-insensitive way and SHOULD either interpret an IANA-registered name as the encoding registered at IANA for that name or treat it as unknown (processors are, of course, not required to support all IANA-registered encodings)."